# Wdio.conf: How to use result object in oncomplete hook

Tags: cucumber, hook, resultset, webdriver-io

How to use Result object in onComplete hook. Actually I wanted to get the pass/fail/skipped count which I can save in text file after execution completion. I am using webdriverIO with cucumber. 
Any help or sample script is highly appriciated!!!!

Answer (score -1):

```js
onComplete: function (exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {

    const resultString = `Finished tests: ${results.finished} \nPassed tests: ${results.passed} \nRetries: ${results.retries} \nFailed tests: ${results.failed}`;
    fs.writeFileSync('./result.txt',resultString);

},
```